# mysql query to move unique rows to temp table

Tags: mysql

I want to create a query to move every unique entry from one table to another temporary table.
I created the following query to get the unique entrys:

```
select date, messageType, zCampaignId, isSenderPolicy, sender, recipient, policy, operator, country, zNumber 
from topcampaigns_HOUR 
group by date, messageType, zCampaignId, isSenderPolicy, sender, recipient, policy, operator, country, zNumber 
having count(*) = 1;
```

and it returns lots of results:

```
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 473  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.000 sec. (+ 0.016 sec. network) */
```

However when I put this into an update I cant seem to get the tmp table updated:

```
UPDATE topcampaigns_HOUR_tmp as b 
INNER JOIN (
   select date, messageType, zCampaignId, isSenderPolicy, sender, recipient, policy, operator, country, zNumber 
   from topcampaigns_HOUR 
   group by date, messageType, zCampaignId, isSenderPolicy, sender, recipient, policy, operator, country, zNumber 
   having count(*) = 1) as a 
SET 
b.date=a.date, 
b.messageType=a.messageType, 
b.zCampaignId=a.zCampaignId, 
b.isSenderPolicy=a.isSenderPolicy, 
b.sender=a.sender, 
b.recipient=a.recipient, 
b.policy=a.policy,
b.operator=a.operator,
b.country=a.country, 
b.zNumber=a.zNumber;
```

which resulted in:

```
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 00:04:25 */
```

I tried an number of things like using:

```
UPDATE topcampaigns_HOUR_tmp JOIN (select date, messageType, zCampaignId, isSenderPolicy, sender, recipient, policy, operator, country, zNumber from topcampaigns_HOUR group by date, messageType, zCampaignId, isSenderPolicy, sender, recipient, policy, operator, country, zNumber having count(*) = 1) a SET 
topcampaigns_HOUR_tmp.date=a.date, 
topcampaigns_HOUR_tmp.messageType=a.messageType, 
topcampaigns_HOUR_tmp.zCampaignId=a.zCampaignId, 
topcampaigns_HOUR_tmp.isSenderPolicy=a.isSenderPolicy, 
topcampaigns_HOUR_tmp.sender=a.sender, 
topcampaigns_HOUR_tmp.recipient=a.recipient, 
topcampaigns_HOUR_tmp.policy=a.policy, 
topcampaigns_HOUR_tmp.operator=a.operator, 
topcampaigns_HOUR_tmp.country=a.country, 
topcampaigns_HOUR_tmp.zNumber=a.zNumber;
```

Again I got:

```
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 00:03:42 */
```

The topcampaigns_HOUR_tmp table never seems to get updated.

What am I doing wrong?

A

Comment: why not insert...select ? e.g. `INSERT INTO temptable SELECT *, COUNT(*) dups FROM table GROUP BY fields HAVING dups = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're adding rows you need `INSERT`, and if you're adding rows from query results you need [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html). Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO topcampaigns_HOUR_tmp (
   date, messageType, zCampaignId, isSenderPolicy, sender,
   recipient, policy, operator, country, zNumber)
select
   date, messageType, zCampaignId, isSenderPolicy, sender,
   recipient, policy, operator, country, zNumber 
from topcampaigns_HOUR 
group by
   date, messageType, zCampaignId, isSenderPolicy, sender,
   recipient, policy, operator, country, zNumber 
having count(*) = 1
```